# Do electromagnetic fields undergo any variation between fields in time, or do such waves just expand in time and in their spherical plane?

Tags: rf, wave, propagation

In literature it is routinely said that an electric field generates a magnetic field, and thus one field creates the other "eternally", and that this explains their propagation.

Am I wrong in thinking these fields do not create each other, but rather move in time, expanding only as they propagate?

I am not sure of my observation, so I am posting it here so that someone can point out where I am wrong.

Comment: How could anyone help you choose between your first paragraph and your second? The only way anyone can make a choice is to look at quantities from experimental results and check them against what rigorously derived theory into those experiments says should happen, quantitatively. How do you imagine I could take your 2nd paragraph, derive it into some specific thought experiment to generate quantitative predictions, and then compare these with similar processes applied to the first? (Or do you imagine there's an underlying reality that we know fully about? [We don't. We just have models.])

Comment: https://youtu.be/uZnXhRgztEg

Comment: I know how electromagnetic fields work, but I don't know what "undergo variation between fields" or "move in time, expanding only as they propagate" means, so I don't know how to answer your question.

Comment: To summarize:
Imagine an "S" in the horizontal plane and that, it just displaces, suffering no phase variation.

The theory points out that, such displacement is due to the creation of fields that create another. That is, an electric field creates a magnetic field, and this, an electric field... as a result of another, and so on to "infinity".

How can I prove that this field only displaces its phases and does not vary it in time?

Comment: I am saying that the wave does not create another wave, electrical or magnetic, but that such a wave only changes phase, and does not undergo variations during propagation.
If I am wrong, please clarify where you contradict any concept of propagation and detection of such waves?

Comment: @JrBennitoBennito There is only one wave, and that's an electromagnetic wave. It has electric and magnetic components, which wax and wane *as if* the variation in one is creating the other.

Comment: @Neil_UK now we're cooking. I believe you should integrate that "as if" into your answer, because as it stands it seems to state that the variation of one field *is* the cause of the other.

Comment: In my model, the magnetic field is just the result of the movement of the electric charge and a “mirror” identical to the electric field.
What makes it propagate is the accumulation of charge in the sum of the conductive medium, when on its return it encounters an incident signal that “expels” it from that medium at the speed of light.

After a few observations, I can't see vectors changing phase over time of their propagation.

Comment: ...As these "fields are static" and in phase with each other, they propagate and when intercepted (antenna) these fields induce potentials as in a VHS tape when passing through a transducer generating a faithful copy of the source of origin.

Of course, the maximum efficiency is given to the wavelength of that wavelength... Better, between intervals of half a cycle of the wave (half wave) in the case of an antenna or even in a waveguide.

Comment: This thesis, as far as I know, does not contradict any principle of propagation of light (OEM).

This propagating wave carries the entire origin story without moving its charges during its propagation, and it is the velocity, its density, its gradient that will induce currents in the antenna.

Still confused?

Answer (score 2):

> In literature it is routinely said that an electric field generates a magnetic field,

It's a current, a movement of charge, that creates a magnetic field. Sometimes that current is an identifiable movement of charged particles, sometimes it's a displacement current in a vacuum, ie a change in electric field. Hand-wavy explanations of electromagnetic propagation do often use that abbreviated terminology though.

> and thus one field creates the other "eternally",

and a changing magnetic field creates an electric field. Yes, they can keep on doing this indefinitely, while each have energy. If something absorbs that energy, then the disturbance will stop.

> and that this explains their propagation.

It's a necessary condition. I'm not sure if it's sufficient, it probably is. I understand that once (I think it was) Heavyside (or was it Maxwell?) understood the electric to magnetic and magnetic to electric phenomena, he realised that wave propagation was possible, and predicted the speed of light based on the measured strengths of the relationships.

> Am I wrong in thinking these fields do not create each other, but rather move in time, expanding only as they propagate?

Really, there is only one field, the electromagnetic field. The electric and magnetic components of it behave as if the changes in one are causing the other. At DC, it's quite easy to think of them separately. Once they begin changing though, both are involved.

The wavefronts y will 'expand' if you consider a point source, with a spherical wavefront advancing away from it. Consider however a plane wave propagating. That does not 'expand', but advances in a particular direction. Except at the edges of course, where it spreads outwards somewhat.

> I am not sure of my observation, so I am postinintog it here so that someone can point out where I am wrong.

I'm not sure I see any observations, but thoughts.

Do bear in mind that all that I've talked about is not reality, but models of whatever reality is. We could just as easily understand light (and other electromagnetic) propagation from a photon point of view, a photon model. Now the plane wave propagation becomes tracing all possible paths that a photon could take from source to destination, and adding up their phases. In practice, we only need to trace the most likely paths, those within the Fresnel zone, a sort of cigar-shaped volume between source and destination surrounding the shortest path. This is precisely the zone where the edges of the plane wave mentioned above 'spread out somewhat'. The two views, different though they are, produce equivalent physics.

Both the electric and the magnetic field store energy, and they can each influence the other. That is what makes wave propagation possible, in fact, having two types of interlinked energy storage makes any type of wave possible.

A more intuitive wave mechanism to understand is perhaps a pressure (sound) wave in air. Here the two energy storage mechanisms are the pressure of the air, and its kinetic energy. An uneven pressure distribution will cause air to rush 'down pressure' gaining kinetic energy. A parcel of moving air, braked by something in front of it, will increase its pressure.

Look at any wave phenomenon, gravity waves on water, transverse waves on a stretched guitar string, there are always two energy storage mechanisms, that can exchange energy between them. In EM waves, these two mechanisms are the electric field, and the magnetic field.

You might have more luck trying to intuit your way into some classical propagating waves, and them come back to electromagnetic ones with the similarities in mind.

Comment: Conduction current, or "movement of charge" creates a magnetic field. But displacement current also creates magnetic fields. But displacement current is a change in electric field, not a "movement of charge". So changing electric fields create magnetic fields.

Comment: There is an inconsistency between your first and second paragraphs.

Comment: I need to say that such a model, as far as I know, does not contradict the classical models, since such a wave exists and with it all its uniqueness in its respective fields.

imagine that such a wave (~) just shifts in time, carrying in itself the model of its origin and, since it carries its original property, there would be no need to suffer phase changes in itself.
For, in their displacement (propagation) they would already bring their variants in time, like mere wagons on a railroad, in front of a fixed observer (antenna).  (...)*

Comment: ...* Without an illustration, it is difficult to clarify my arguments further.
But let's say the wave phases are numbers shifting in time, from left to right, like locomotive cars:
10,09,08,07,06,05,04,03,02,01 >>>>>> Note that the variant does not need to be varying itself, since it carries all its source variant; enough is fixed and its density will cross the reference point in time, as it moves (propagates) like the numbers above.

And then my questions arise: does such an announcement contradict the classic models and where?

Comment: (Sorry for the confusing and tedious explanation, but I believe someone will understand).

Answer (score 1):

> In literature it is routinely said that an electric field generates a magnetic field

A *changing* electric field will generate a magnetic field. That, I believe, is what the literature routinely says, and that literature is correct.

Ampere's Law with Maxwell's Addition states that

\$\nabla \times B = \mu_0 \left(J + \epsilon_0\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}\right)\$

where \$B\$ is the magnetic field, \$J\$ is conduction current density, and \$E\$ is the electric field.

The conduction current is the movement of charges.

\$\epsilon_0\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}\$ is the displacement current density, and this is simply the rate of change of the electric field times a constant.

> Am I wrong in thinking these fields do not create each other

You are wrong in the sense that a *change* in either field is necessarily associated with the existence of the other field. However, the word "create" might be somewhat ambiguous.

> but rather move in time, expanding only as they propagate?

I am not sure that this statement has a mathematical meaning or testable significance.